# Где и как правильно делать расширенный поиск, с множеством зависимых таблиц?

Tags: php, yii2

В *Yii2* удобно искать в `GridView` на основе `SearchModel` и метода `search`. Однако бывает так, что нужно сделать "расширенный поиск", который будет довольно сложным, содержать "отсылки" на другие модели (таблицы), множество отдельных блоков, в которых поиск осуществляется по связанным таблицам (может даже через одну или две), но которые связаны с текущей сущностью.

Как правильно поступать в данном случае и что делать? Делать ещё один метод `advanced-search`  и строить логику для расширенного поиска там? а не смешивать её в `search`? А использовать какую-то кастомную форму, унаследованную от `Model`? А как оперировать и обычным поиском и расширенным в одном методе контроллера (например `indexAction` который, как правило, рендерит таблицу с данными сущности)?

Comment: Делаете там же,  а зачем разделять? У вас же все связано с текущей сущностью.

Answer (score 0):

Сразу предупреждаю - костыль :) Создаете новую модель формы расширенного поиска `AdvancedSearchForm`. В ней описываете все поля которые пользователь у Вас может заполнить для расширенного поиска - скажем дату из одной таблицы, название из другой и тд. В Вашей модели поиска создаете дополнительные `виртуальные` поля по аналогии с полями формы `AdvancedSearchForm`. После чего в внутрь `GridView` выводите эти поля из модели поиска, там где у Вас поля фильтра, но скрытыми.

Как действует. После того как пользователь заполнит форму поиска и нажмет кнопку "Искать" Вы с помощью `javascript` перекидываете значения полей формы в такие же поля но внутри `GridView` и делаете на любом поле фильтра `onchange` - `GridView` посчитает, что Вы типа руками в поле фильтра ввели значение и нажали `enter`. Ну, а дальше стройте свой запрос поиска внутри `searchModel` в зависимости от новых полей с их значениями.

У меня так работает. :)